# Can laptops be used for DualView technology?

Tags: laptop, multiple-monitors, lcd, crt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is a free/open source tool to allow me to control another computer or use it as a second monitor?](https://superuser.com/questions/129221/what-is-a-free-open-source-tool-to-allow-me-to-control-another-computer-or-use-i)

Is it possible to align two laptops and configure them to use DualView technology? Or is this only suitable for LCD's and CRT's?

Comment: Sorry, but what exactly are you asking here?  What do you mean by `DualView` technology?  I know you can have a "virtual" monitor over the network, but I'm not sure what you mean when you say you want to "align two laptops"...

Comment: Sorry, I'll clarify. Align two laptops (put them side by side). DualView aka Multiple Monitors (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-monitor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a program like [MaxiVista](http://www.maxivista.com/) to share screens across the network.  The software will emulate a virtual device on your "primary" computer, and stream the display output across the network.  The "secondary" client computer will then display the received result, giving the illusion of dual monitors connected directly to a single computer.

As an alternative, you can use a distributed KVM software like [Input Director](http://www.inputdirector.com/) to share the input between both computers, giving the illusion of using two laptops as dual monitors.  However, both laptops will still run independently - this will only allow for you to contol both with a single keyboard/mouse pair.